# SSH to jump host, to final host, then tmux

Tags: ssh, tmux, netcat

In my ssh config, I have

```
Host jumpHostNick
     HostName jumphost.com
     User username

Host finalHostNick
     User username
     ProxyCommand ssh jumpHostNick nc finalHostURL 22
```

I would like to supplement this by having it run `tmux attach -d` when it gets to the final host. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-W` rather then the `netcat`:

```
Host jumpHostNick
     HostName jumphost.com
     User username

Host finalHostNick
     User username
     ProxyCommand ssh -W finalHostURL:22 jumpHostNick
```

If you want to run `tmux attach -d`, you should also add to the `finalHostNick`:

```
RequestTTY yes
```

and then connect using `ssh finalHostNick -t tmux attach -d`, or just setup bash alias:

```
alias ssh-final='ssh finalHostNick -t tmux attach -d'
```

in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: `ssh finalHostNick -t tmux attach -d` does the trick. Why use -W rather than `netcat`?

Comment: Because `netcat` needs a binary on the jumpbox. Using `-W` does the same, but you don't rely on `netcat` being installed on the jumpbox.

Comment: Is it possible to include `-t tmux attach -d` in  the ssh config?

Comment: The RequestTTY yes, but the remote command no. But you can create bash alias instead.

Comment: Using `-W` instead of netcat has the strange effect of making the title of my ssh window the same as my local terminal windows, rather than `remoteuser@remotehost: ~`. Is it possible to fix this?